# How to add cookies in request

Tags: c#, networking, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to create http request using

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadURL);
  
                                        
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I have all cookies used in string format : cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2;
How do I append this cookies in string format when making request

Comment: Yes the below answer answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
request.Headers["Cookie"] = "cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2";
```

Comment: Is this supported, I dont see any documentation for this